# Modify ::after of an element when an input field's (child of that same element) placeholder text gets hidden

Tags: css, css-selectors

We know doing `.parent::after` will create an HTML element as the last child of `.parent`. I want to modify `.parent::after` when `.parent__input`'s placeholder text is hidden due to typing into the input field. Here is what I did—

```css
.parent::after {
  content: "placeholder visible";
}

.parent__input:not(.parent__input:placeholder-shown) ~ .parent::after {
  content: "placeholder hidden";
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <input type="text" placeholder="just some text..." class="parent__input">
</div>
```

`.parent__input:not(.parent__input:placeholder-shown)` selects all those `.parent__input` whose placeholder text is hidden, hence the `:not(.parent__input:placeholder-shown)` part. And since, `.parent::after` is a child of `.parent`, and therefore a sibling of `.parent__input` I could just select `.parent::after` using general sibling combinator `~`, which I did above.

But it isn't working. And I want to do it with pure CSS. Thank you.

Comment: You can not contact parent using CSS selector.

Comment: But I can select siblings, and since `.parent::after` is a sibling of `.parent__input`, I should select it.

Comment: The **pseudo element** is just that. It is not in the DOM so it is not a sibling.

Answer (score 0):

You can not contact parent using CSS selector.

But you can contact the sibling.

```css
.sibling::after {
  content: "placeholder visible";
}

.parent__input:not(.parent__input:placeholder-shown) ~ .sibling::after {
  content: "placeholder hidden";
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <input type="text" placeholder="just some text..." class="parent__input">
  <span class="sibling" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I did, but it requires extra markup. So, I thought maybe if I could do that without adding extra markup.  And as I've already told you, `.parent::after` is a sibling of `.parent__input`, so it should work, but it doesn't.